# Multiple Repos in Release definition

Tags: git, azure-devops, repository, continuous-deployment

I have multiple Repos connected to CD providing input to it in the form of data

[Current picture of CD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ffLh.png)

The problem is every time when any update in data is there in any of the Repository (Repo1 or Repo2 or Repo3), data from all connected repository is downloaded which takes substantial time.

However, I want that **only those files are downloaded which are changed**. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are actually artifacts. It's able to do this.

> - **Option 1: use PowerShell task to download the updated files in the    latest commit**
>
> You can remove the git repo from the "Artifacts" section on the
>   release pipeline and get the repository in another way, such as
>   powershell or cmd task.  Use that kind of task to pull the changes
>   from the git repository.
>
> - **Option 2: only download the latest commit from git repo**
>
> You can also specify the shallow fetch depth as 1, then the down
>   artifact step will only download the latest commit. And it will reduce
>   the artifact size sharply.

More details  please refer Marina Liu's reply in this question: [Only download changes to git repo in VSTS release pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52280056/only-download-changes-to-git-repo-in-vsts-release-pipeline)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think this is possible with Azure DevOps right now, it doesn't store a "cache" of your repositories, so it will always re-download them.